# Inconsistency when parsing year-weeknum string to date

Tags: python, date, datetime

When parsing year-weeknum strings, I came across an inconsistency when comparing the results from `%W` and `%U` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)):

**What works:**

```py
from datetime import datetime

print("\nISO:") # for reference...
for i in range(1,8): # %u is 1-based
    print(datetime.strptime(f"2019-01-{i}", "%G-%V-%u"))
# ISO:
# 2018-12-31 00:00:00
# 2019-01-01 00:00:00
# 2019-01-02 00:00:00
# ...  
    
# %U -> week start = Sun
# first Sunday 2019 was 2019-01-06
print("\n %U:")    
for i in range(0,7):
    print(datetime.strptime(f"2019-01-{i}", "%Y-%U-%w"))
#  %U:
# 2019-01-06 00:00:00
# 2019-01-07 00:00:00
# 2019-01-08 00:00:00
# ...
```

**What is unexpected**:

```py
# %W -> week start = Mon
# first Monday 2019 was 2019-01-07
print("\n %W:")    
for i in range(0,7):
    print(datetime.strptime(f"2019-01-{i}", "%Y-%W-%w"))
#  %W:
# 2019-01-13 00:00:00 ## <-- ?! expected 2019-01-06
# 2019-01-07 00:00:00 
# 2019-01-08 00:00:00
# 2019-01-09 00:00:00
# 2019-01-10 00:00:00
# 2019-01-11 00:00:00
# 2019-01-12 00:00:00
```

The date jumping from 2019-01-13 to 2019-01-07? What's going on here? I don't see any ambiguities in the [calendar for 2019](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2019&country=9)... I also tried to parse the same dates in `rust` with chrono, and it fails for the `%W` directive -> [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a38796a60d86028977c56f76f0e386be). A jump backwards in Python and an error in Rust, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That week goes from Monday January 7 to Sunday January 13.

`%w` is documented as *"Weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday."*. So `0` means Sunday (= January 13), and `1` means Monday (= January 7).

Answer (score -2):

In your code, you're trying to parse the string "2019-01-0" as a day of a year, which is not a valid day. That's why you're encountering an unexpected result when using the %W format code.

If you want to parse a date, you should specify a value that is bigger then 1 not 0.

Also keep it might help to keep the style consistent with f-string

```py
f'(2019-01-{i:02d}')
```

which will add the leading 0 when necessary like the following.

```
2019-01-00
2019-01-01
2019-01-02
2019-01-03
2019-01-04
2019-01-05
2019-01-06
```

Here is your modified code:

```
for i in range(0,7):
    print(datetime.strptime(f"2019-01-{i}", "%Y-%W-%w"))
```

Comment: `%Y-%W-%w`, means year, weeknum, weekday. Weekday can be `0`.